# Vue alert message handling

Tags: jhipster

I love the vue.js impl.. so easy and fast to develop with but it appears that the error handling for api errors is not working (not the same as with react.js anyway).

E.g. if I try to save an entity with a field value that is supposed to be unique (but is not) then the page does not display any error alert at all. I do see one in the js console, but it looks like its not handled in the ui code.

Is there something more I need to do ?

Comment: you should open an issue on github

Comment: strange the way its released like this though